# send all .xml requests to proxy

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-proxy

I have an Angular application that pulls in content from a CMS for articles via an API.  I want to utilize the XML sitemap generated by the CMS.  The CMS is hosted at content.example.com and the Angular site is the www. What I would like to do is catch all .xml requests and load the content site by proxy.  What I have in my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
RewriteRule ^\.*?\.xml$ https://content.example.com/$2 [P,L]
```

However, that is not working.  Fairly new to mod rewrite so I am assuming my logic is off.  Not finding a lot of examples of this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your rule this way

```
# Only apply next rule when domain is www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
# (Proxy) rewrite all xml files to its proxy equivalent
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.xml$ https://content.example.com/$1.xml [P]
```